# strtok when no data after a delimiter

Tags: c, strtok

I needed to know when there was no data between two delimiters so I found the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705844/need-to-know-when-no-data-appears-between-two-token-separators-using-strtok) on Stack Overflow.

```
char *strtok_single (char * str, char const * delims)
{
  static char  *src = NULL;
  char  *p,  * ret = 0;

  if (str != NULL)
    src = str;

  if (src == NULL)
    return NULL;

  if ((p = strpbrk (src, delims)) != NULL) {
    *p  = 0;
    ret = src;
    src = ++p;

  } else if (*src) {
    ret = src;
    src = NULL;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Sampling the function

```
char delims[] = ",";
char data  [] = "foo,bar,,baz,biz,,";

char *p = strtok_single(data, delims);

while (p) {
  printf ("%s\n", *p ? p : "<empty>");

  p = strtok_single (NULL, delims);
}
```

Output

```
foo                                                                                                                                                                                
bar                                                                                                                                                                                
<empty>                                                                                                                                                                            
baz                                                                                                                                                                                
biz                                                                                                                                                                                
<empty>
// missing another <empty>
```

With the current code, it does not process data after the last ',' There should be one more empty field. I am unsure how to get the correct output.

Comment: Why aren't you actually using `strtok()`?

Comment: Tip: Function calls usually have a syntax like `f(...)` with no space, while constructs like `if` or `while` get special treatment so they stand out, as in `if (...)` or `while (...)` with a space. Spacing out your function calls makes them look broken.

Comment: @tadman It collapses multiple consecutive delimiters.

Comment: You can do that by wrapping around `strtok()` if you prefer. There's no need to reinvent `strtok()`. Just have it skip a token if you get a zero length result.

Comment: Using strtok when there is no data between two delimiters such as ",," it will count it as a single token. I need to know that there is no data there as I am assigning values to them.

Comment: From whence cometh your code for `strtok_single()`?  Is it [SO 3029-4129](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30294129/15168)?  Should you not say so?

Comment: If you have strsep, use it instead of strtok. That's what it's for. If you don't have it, there are open-source implementations available.

Comment: @tadman: Probably because `strtok()` treats multiple consecutive separator characters as a single delimiter, rather than as separating multiple fields.  And no, you can't just wrap `strtok()` to get the effect.  You might be able to use `strsep()` instead — but that's just as much a non-standard function as `strtok_single()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler edited post to show where I got code

Comment: OK; that's a different SO question (SO 0870-5844) from what I suggested.  Try looking at SO 3029-4192; it might help.  Also, do look at `strsep()`.  I have a chunk of test code kicking around which I wrote in response to a question (on SO) that I can no longer identify, so it probably got deleted.  It shows `strsep()` at work, and it can report on the empty field at the end of the string `",abc,def,,ghi,"` (and the one at the beginning) when the delimiter is `,`.  That seems to be what you're after, is it not?  You could look at [SO 5824-4300](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58244300/15168) too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, that is what im looking for. I will take a look at those. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `strsep` instead of `strtok`. Indeed, `strsep` supports empty fields: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7218632/2641719)

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
        char delims[] = ",";
        char data  [] = "foo,bar,,baz,biz,,";
        char *p = strdup(data);
        char * tok;
        while ((tok = strsep(&p, delims)) != NULL) {
                printf ("%s\n", *tok ? tok : "<empty>");
        }
        free(p);
        return 0;
}
```

The ouput:

```
foo
bar
<empty>
baz
biz
<empty>
<empty>
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution. However, on the code Im working on my data is a csv file and for some reason, the while loop isn't evaluating as true when the data is coming from a csv file, but I might have others issues idk.

Comment: @Ayelir: note that a CSV file can, in general, also have quoted fields, and those quoted fields might contain commas. For example, `"abc,\"def,ghi\",jkl"` is a C string containing 3 fields in a CSV format.  The middle field is enclosed in quotes and contains `"def,ghi"`.  Without seeing your data, it is hard to know whether this is actually your problem, but you should be aware of the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The issue with my code wasn't actually the csv. I wasn't updating the ptr with each line being read from the file.