# C strtok check edge case where delimiter is first/last character or consecutive delimiters

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I'm using `strtok` in order to parse an argument list where every argument is separated by a comma, e.g `arg1, arg2, arg3` and I need to check for these 3 erros in the format:

1. `,arg1, arg2, arg3`
2. `arg1, arg2, arg3,`
3. `arg1,, arg2, arg3`

for the first case `strtok` digest the first comma, and return the first arg, in the second case `strtok` return `NULL` as it finished digesting the string, and the third case is similar to the first `strtok` just digest the consecutive commas. Is there a way in C to detect those errors apart from writing a new function for breaking the string?

I tried to make my version of `strtok` to check for this

```
int my_strtok(char * str, char delim, char ** token) {
    int res = 0;
    static char * next;
    char * ptr;

    if (NULL != str) {
        next = str;
    }

    ptr = next;
    while (delim != *next && 0 != *next) {
        next++;
    }

    if (delim == *next) {
        *next = 0;
        next++;
    }
    if (1 == next - ptr) {
        res = -1; /* error */
    }

    if (0 == *ptr) {
        *token = NULL;
    } else {
        *token = ptr;
    }

    return res;
}
```

But I would rather have something standard.

**PS I need something conforming to ANSI C**

Comment: The standard functions don't support what you need.

Comment: Consider the non-standard `strsep()` if available, otherwise make your own parser. Or, if there is always also a separating space as apparently shown, use that as the delimiter string and detect the commas in the extracted tokens.

Comment: The man page for strsep says "The strsep() function was introduced as a replacement for strtok(), since the latter cannot handle empty fields.  However, strtok() conforms to C89/C99 and hence is more portable."  So it looks like that does exactly what you want as long as the standard library contains the function.  This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218625/what-are-the-differences-between-strtok-and-strsep-in-c

Comment: If you want to make your own have a look at the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244300/getting-the-error-undefined-reference-to-strsep-with-clang-and-mingw